# Make These Lines Thick

Tags: logo, line-art

Hello I am only 3 days old in using Inkscape and I drew this hand using a Straight Line tool (Shift+F6) but I do not know how to thicken them. Please help
Thank you :)
[image]

Comment: Quote: Hi, have you taken a look at the Fill and Stroke toolbar? You can find it at Object → Fill and Stroke, or with the shortcut Shift + Ctrl + F. In the third tab of this toolbar, Stroke style, you can change the line width :). source [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=13665#p52920)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right dialog Object > Fill and Stroke is already visible at the right edge of your screen. Goto  its tab "Stroke style" and adjust stroke width. Before it select all lines you want to adjust.

There is also possible to change the line end styles. You might want to change them, too because if the stroke is wide, the sharp corners can be disturbing. Round line ends fit in any angle if they are drawn to exactly same point. Be sure that you have snapping to node points ON when you draw.